# Twisted memory leak when connect attempt failed

Tags: python, memory, twisted, memory-leaks

i was being tortured twisted memory leaks.

Here is my code:

```
# Python:  Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
# Twisted: Twisted-12.2.0.win32-py2.6
# OS:      Windows 7 (64bit)
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class Echo(Protocol):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'Echo.__del__'

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Echo.connectionMade'
        self.transport.write('Hello world!')


class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'EchoClientFactory.__del__'

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started connecting ...'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'connected. %r' % addr
        return Echo()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed.'


def connect(ip, port):
    factory = EchoClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP(ip, port, factory)


##Start
import gc
gc.enable()
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

# Trying to connect to a port that does not exist
connect('127.0.0.1', 7777)

reactor.callLater(5, reactor.stop)
reactor.run()

# Show garbages
print "gc.collect()"
gc.collect()
print 'gc.garbage:', len(gc.garbage)

for i, item in enumerate(gc.garbage):
    print '%d) %r' % (i + 1, item)
```

after run, gc shows memory leak is happen:

after run, gc shows memory leak is happen:

after run, gc shows memory leak is happen:

```
Started connecting ...
Connection failed.
EchoClientFactory.__del__
gc.collect()
gc: collectable <Client 02CEA7B0>
gc: collectable <dict 02CEFC00>
gc: collectable <tuple 02B13FD0>
gc: collectable <list 02CD2558>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 02818E40>
gc: collectable <instancemethod 02CF04B8>
gc: collectable <tuple 02B205F8>
gc.garbage: 7
1) <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('127.0.0.1', 7777) at 2cea7b0>
2) {'_tempDataBuffer': [], 'protocol': None, '_tempDataLen': 0, 'realAddress': ('127.0.0.1', 7777), 'doRead': <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('127.0.0.1', 7777) at 2cea7b0>>, 'doWrite': <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('127.0.0.1', 7777) at 2cea7b0>>, 'reactor': <twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor object at 0x02699D50>, 'addr': ('127.0.0.1', 7777)}
3) ('127.0.0.1', 7777)
4) []
5) <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('127.0.0.1', 7777) at 2cea7b0>>
6) <bound method Client.doConnect of <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('127.0.0.1', 7777) at 2cea7b0>>
7) ('127.0.0.1', 7777)
```

Only happened when the connect failed.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Never bothered with garbage collection in python, but it's pretty usual to have garbage in the memory. Especially when you try to run a method which fails (note that all your garbage is associated with this failed attempt to connect to a non-existent port). I'd just collect the garbage and move on, why worry about this?

Comment: Thank you for your notice! Because my program needs to manager hundreds devices, connect to and get status from them, if disconnected or connection failed, it needs to reconnect with in a few seconds. And this program needs to serve forever, so memory leak is a big problem for me.

Comment: Right, I see. But can't you just collect the garbage and accept that, every no and then, some memory will not be freed "automatically" when certain objects are deleted (e.g. when a connection fails)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution.

In the twisted source code, open this file: *`Python26\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py`*

```
class BaseConnector(styles.Ephemeral):
    .
    .
    .

    def connectionFailed(self, reason):
        self.cancelTimeout()
        if self.transport.doWrite == self.transport.doConnect:    # 1
            del self.transport.doRead                             # 2
            del self.transport.doWrite                            # 3
        self.transport = None
        self.state = "disconnected"
        self.factory.clientConnectionFailed(self, reason)
        if self.state == "disconnected":
            # factory hasn't called our connect() method
            self.factory.doStop()
            self.factoryStarted = 0
    .
    .
    .
```

Lines marked with 1,2,3 are my newly added.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `__del__` to a program most likely *adds* object leaks to it.  The presence of `__del__` on an object in a cycle prevents the entire cycle from being collected.

Try debugging your actual program without using `__del__` anywhere.  Or if your actual program uses `__del__`, try getting rid of it.